# Automator Change to directory of dropped files before running Shell command

Tags: applescript, command-line, bash, automator, folders

Seems extremely simple, but I can't figure it out...

I want to be able to change to the directory (folder) where the dropped file is located before running my shell script on that file.

So either I change to the directory first with Automator, then pass that argument to Shell Script or Applescript

or I change to the directory inside of Applescript or Shell before running my Shell command.  pls help

Comment: Please post an answer below! Glad you got it working!

Comment: As coded, the solution you posted as part of your question, which really should have been posted as a separate answer and not an edit to the question, will fail with e.g. **Can’t get POSIX path of {alias "...", alias "..."}** if more then one file is dropped. Use `item 1 of input` to act only of the first file dropped or use a repeat loop. You also need to properly double quote variables to prevent globbing and word splitting. As the current code fails if the dropped file has spaces anywhere in its fully qualified pathname. You also need to use `Fold's quoted form` for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy in `zsh`. You can use the `:h` option to a variable to refer to the `head` of its full path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh -f

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin"

for i in "$@"
do

    FILE="$i"

    cd "$FILE:h"

    # do other things here

done
```

In a shell like `bash` you would need to use the `dirname` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin"

for i in "$@"
do

    FILE="$i"

    DIR=$(dirname "$FILE")

    cd "$DIR"

    # do other things here

done
```

Comment: Ah. I didn’t think about that. I have made changes to handle multiple files with the `for i` loop.

Comment: nice way to do it.

Comment: You really do not need the `FILE` and `DIR` as `i` can be used directly, e.g. `for i in "$@"; do cd "$i:h"; done` for **zsh** and `for i in "$@"; do cd "$(dirname "$i")"; done` for **bash**. I'd also use error handling, e.g." `cd "$(dirname "$i")" || exit`

Comment: `i` can be used directly, but I prefer to use more meaningful variable names, as they make debugging later much easier, especially some months later when I’ve most likely forgotten everything about the script, what it does, and how it does it.

Comment: RE: "especially some months later when I’ve most likely forgotten everything about the script, what it does, and how it does it." ... Isn't that what commenting code is for? (Rhetorical question.)

Answer (score 0):

[Final working code]

Here is the function which takes in the fully qualified file path as an argument, Opens Terminal, and performs a bash script.

The script defines the `pathname` and `folder` variables, then changes to the `folder` directory then calls an external function "fds" and passes the `pathname` argument to it.

Again, thanks for all the comments, especially user3439894 as his suggestion below was spot on.

```
on process_fds(fdsFile)
    set Fold to POSIX path of fdsFile
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "pathname=" & Fold's quoted form & ";folder=\"$(dirname \"$pathname\")\";cd \"$folder\";fds \"$pathname\""
    end tell
end process_fds
```

Comment: The _code_ you've posted is incomplete as you only show a _handler_ without showing how it's being called or the rest of the _code_ in the **Run AppleScript** _action_. The _code_ is also not properly quoted and should be as e.g. `do script "pathname=" & Fold's quoted form & "; folder=\"$(dirname \"$pathname\")\"; cd \"$folder\"; fds \"$pathname\""`